# Should I use final for all the unchanged variables in Java?

Tags: java, spring, constants, final

As far as I see, final is commonly used comparing to the same situations in `C#`. There is no final in `C#`, but `sealed` is not heavily used like this. So, can we say that; if the value will not be changed, or at least we are sure, then we should use `final` for all the situations e.g. variable definitions, parameters, ...?

```
private final Integer LIMIT = 10;
private final String NAME = "John";
```

or

```
default Optional<EmployeeDTO> findByUuid(final UUID uuid) {
  ...
}
```

And should we use capital letters for the final variable names as `constant` values?

Comment: Use it if you think it makes your code clearer or might prevent an error. You don't need to use it everywhere possible. That would be cumbersome.

Comment: Note in Java the `ALL_CAPS` convention is typically reserved for fields that are both `static` _and_ `final` (that includes enum constants). Fields that are just `final` use the standard `camelCase` convention.

Comment: @khelwood In this scene, I think it only helps to prevent from further value assign and there is no difference for performance, etc. Is that true?

Comment: In the example you gave, `LIMIT` and `NAME` are actual constants (there's no means to set them to anything else), so you ought to make then `static final`. As for other cases... it's preference. I personally like when they're final, but adding the modifier clutters the code, so I usually don't.

Comment: And, what about the constant values in Java? Is the only difference `final static` to use constant values? **AND** should I use **capital** letters for `final` variables as `constant` values in Java?

Comment: `final` fields _do_ have significant performance advantages, particularly in multithreaded code, since they have guarantees that they will never change. `final` method parameters don't. _Do not_ use `SNAKE_CASE` for `final` fields; use `camelCase` like for variables.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks Slaw, I have just seen your reply. Then I will use camelCase for final and CAPITAL for `static final` meaning `constant` in Java. Is that true?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Good explanations, thanks.

Comment: I think *effectively final* variables have the same performance advantages.

Comment: @khelwood Sorry, do not understand what you mean. Do you explain a little bit further? Do you agree with **chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-**  for performance wise?

Comment: "effectively final" means a local variable that the compiler can tell does not ever get changed, so it can treat it as final even if it isn't declared final.

Comment: Then, can we say that we **should** use `final` for global values, but there is no difference when using `final` for local values and method parameters?

Comment: @khelwood Any reply please?

Comment: You already got my opinion in my first comment.

Comment: @khelwood Thanks, but I am confused with all of comments. So, could you please that **Then, can we say that we should use final for global values, but there is no difference when using final for local values and method parameters?**